# Why does the compiler not resolve this call to a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

In below program why does the compiler generate an error for the call to the `printMax` template function and not the call to the `printMaxInts` function?

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A>
void printMax(A a,A b)
{
   A c = a>b?a:b;

   std::cout<<c;
}

void printMaxInts(int a ,int b)
{
   int c = a>b?a:b;

   std::cout<<c;

}

int main()
{
   printMax(1,14.45);

   printMaxInts(1,24);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for the compiler to deduce the template parameter `A` from the arguments passed to the function template, both arguments, `a` and `b` must have the same type.

Your arguments are of type `int` and `double`, and so the compiler can't deduce what type it should actually use for `A`.  Should `A` be `int` or should it be `double`?

You can fix this by making both arguments have the same type:

```
printMax(1.0, 14.45);
```

or by explicitly specifying the template parameter:

```
printMax<double>(1, 14.45);
```

The reason that the call to the non-template function can be called is that the compiler does not need to deduce the type of the parameters:  it knows the type of the parameters because you said what they were in the function declaration:

```
void printMaxInts(int a, int b)
```

Both `a` and `b` are of type `int`.  When you pass a `double` as an argument to this function, the `double -> int` standard conversion is performed on the argument and the function is called with the resulting `int`.

Comment: Another fix is to take two template arguments, perform conversion inside the fuction.

Answer (score 1):

The following code builds on James's answer.  You'll notice that I've taken out the conditional expression: I've done this because the result clauses to that expression must have the same type, which imposes an additional restriction on A and B.

The only requirements on A and B in this version of the code is that there's an operator<() that related them (or one can be converted to the other), and that the requisite operator<<() functions exist.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
void printMax(A a, B b)
{    
    if (a < b) 
    {
        cout << b;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << a;
    }
}
```